# Optimizing multi-table left join query using group by

Tags: postgresql

We are running PostgreSQL 9.5 and lately user reported that he is unable to log in. After investigating the issue the problem seems to be that the query to retrieve user information is executing for about 40s.

The query is:

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, u.permission_rank, u.name_color, u.group_name, u.total_exp, u.bonus_exp, u.hats, u.heads, u.bodys, u.feets, u.current_hat, u.current_hat_color, u.current_head, u.current_head_color, u.current_body, u.current_body_color, u.current_feet, u.current_feet_color, u.speed, u.accel, u.jump, u.last_online, 
       array_remove(array_agg(DISTINCT f.friend_user_id), NULL) AS friends, 
       array_remove(array_agg(DISTINCT i.ignored_user_id), NULL) AS ignored, 
       array_remove(array_agg(DISTINCT (c.level_id, c.finish_time)), (NULL::integer, NULL::integer)) AS campaign_runs, 
       array_remove(array_agg(DISTINCT (l.date, l.uses)), (NULL::date, NULL::integer)) AS daily_luck 
FROM base.users u 
LEFT JOIN base.friends f ON u.id = f.user_id 
LEFT JOIN base.ignored i ON u.id = i.user_id 
LEFT JOIN base.campaigns_runs c ON c.user_id = u.id 
LEFT JOIN base.users_daily_luck l ON l.user_id = u.id 
WHERE u.id = 2293 
GROUP BY u.id 
LIMIT 1
```

Running EXPLAIN ANALYZE will result to the following:

```
Limit  (cost=29.38..11110.10 rows=1 width=251) (actual time=40993.111..40993.112 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=29.38..11110.10 rows=1 width=251) (actual time=40993.109..40993.109 rows=1 loops=1)
        Group Key: u.id
        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=29.38..5351.67 rows=460672 width=251) (actual time=0.138..805.111 rows=4721888 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (u.id = f.user_id)
              ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=11.14..131.99 rows=7552 width=247) (actual time=0.098..20.767 rows=77408 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (u.id = i.user_id)
                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=5.09..40.66 rows=128 width=243) (actual time=0.052..2.850 rows=1312 loops=1)
                          Join Filter: (l.user_id = u.id)
                          ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.57..26.74 rows=4 width=235) (actual time=0.026..0.397 rows=41 loops=1)
                                Join Filter: (c.user_id = u.id)
                                ->  Index Scan using users_pkey on users u  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=227) (actual time=0.012..0.013 rows=1 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: (id = 2293)
                                ->  Index Scan using user_id_campaign on campaigns_runs c  (cost=0.29..18.39 rows=4 width=12) (actual time=0.008..0.326 rows=41 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: (user_id = 2293)
                          ->  Materialize  (cost=4.52..12.08 rows=32 width=12) (actual time=0.001..0.021 rows=32 loops=41)
                                ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on users_daily_luck l  (cost=4.52..11.92 rows=32 width=12) (actual time=0.021..0.088 rows=32 loops=1)
                                      Recheck Cond: (user_id = 2293)
                                      Heap Blocks: exact=7
                                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on user_id_daily  (cost=0.00..4.52 rows=32 width=0) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=32 loops=1)
                                            Index Cond: (user_id = 2293)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=5.31..5.31 rows=59 width=8) (actual time=0.039..0.039 rows=59 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 11kB
                          ->  Index Only Scan using ignored_pkey on ignored i  (cost=0.28..5.31 rows=59 width=8) (actual time=0.009..0.024 rows=59 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (user_id = 2293)
                                Heap Fetches: 0
              ->  Hash  (cost=17.48..17.48 rows=61 width=8) (actual time=0.035..0.035 rows=61 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 11kB
                    ->  Index Only Scan using friends_pkey on friends f  (cost=0.28..17.48 rows=61 width=8) (actual time=0.009..0.022 rows=61 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (user_id = 2293)
                          Heap Fetches: 0
Planning time: 0.637 ms
Execution time: 40993.272 ms
```

All of the tables are indexed on the column user_id.

Comment: Does `base.users.id` is primary key? Think about correlated subqueries (in FROM or in SELECT) or about selecting each separate table in CTE.

Comment: Yes it is primary key. CTEs could be the answer, wondering will it cause issues when selecting multiple users with one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lateral joins to avoid grouping the entire result:

```sql
SELECT u.id, 
       u.username, u.permission_rank, u.name_color, u.group_name, 
       u.total_exp, u.bonus_exp, u.hats, u.heads, u.bodys, u.feets, 
       u.current_hat, u.current_hat_color, u.current_head, u.current_head_color, 
       u.current_body, u.current_body_color, 
       u.current_feet, u.current_feet_color, 
       u.speed, u.accel, u.jump, u.last_online, 
       f.friends, 
       i.ignored, 
       c.campaign_runs, 
       l.daily_luck 
FROM base.users u 
  LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    select array_agg(fr.friend_user_id) as friends
    from base.friends fr
    where fr.user_id = u.id
    group by fr.user_id
  ) f ON true
  LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    select array_agg(ig.ignored_user_id) as ignored
    from base.ignored ig
    where ig.user_id = u.id
  ) i ON true
  LEFT JOIN (
    select array_agg( (cr.level_id, cr.finish_time) ) as campaign_runs
    from base.campaigns_runs cr
    where cr.user_id = u.id
  ) c ON true
  LEFT JOIN (
    select array_agg( (udl.date, udl.uses) ) as daily_luck
    from base.users_daily_luck udl
    where udl.user_id = u.id
  ) l ON true
WHERE u.id = 2293 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Yes, nice. Also this way, the `DISTINCT` inside the aggregates will likely not be needed.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: probably yes, but I wasn't sure.

Comment: This is something I tried to do but somehow didn't get it to work. This has no performance problems and plays nicely with multiple results. Also I can get rid of those useless DISTINCT and array_removes :)

Answer (score 1):

Test

```
WITH 
u AS ( SELECT * 
       FROM base.users
       WHERE id = 2293),
f AS ( SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT base.friends.friend_user_id) AS friends
       FROM base.friends, u
       WHERE u.id = base.friends.user_id),
i AS ( SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT base.ignored.ignored_user_id) AS ignored
       FROM base.ignored, u
       WHERE u.id = base.ignored.user_id),
c AS ( SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT (base.campaigns.level_id, base.campaigns.finish_time)) AS campaign_runs
       FROM base.campaigns, u
       WHERE u.id = base.campaigns.user_id),
l AS ( SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT (base.users_daily_luck.date, base.users_daily_luck.uses)) AS daily_luck
       FROM base.users_daily_luck, u
       WHERE u.id = base.users_daily_luck.user_id)
SELECT * -- replace with fields list to exclude 
         -- unnesessary fields from base.users table
         -- or to solve name duplicates
FROM u,f,i,c,l
```

PS. Think does DISTINCTs in CTEs are nesessary...

Comment: Complains about missing FROM-clause entry for table "u" on line 7

Comment: @Joni Oops... sorry, edited. And table aliases for all fields added.

Comment: This does not play nicely with multiple results

Comment: @Joni *multiple results* **IMPOSSIBLE.** 1st CTE gives 1 record - `id` is PK. CTEs 2-5 gives 1 record each - no GROUP BY in them. Cartesian of 5 tables 1 record each produces 1 output record with guarantee. You make a misprint somewhere.

Comment: @Akina they mean if the first CTE has a different WHERE clause with multiple rows as result. You'd need to rewrite your joins in the other CTEs and the final SELECT to take care of that. Joni, that is not hard to do.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ ??? I don't understand how we can obtain multiple records while selecting by one literal value of primary key field (`WHERE u.id = 2293` in OP's query). And what do you mean telling "different WHERE"? I see nothing about it.